# How to pass data from one XAML page contained in another XAML page using views

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an XAML page contained in another XAML page (using Xamarin.Forms). I want to pass data from one to the other.

My main page is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.ItemScreen"
             xmlns:views="MyApp.TopMenu">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <views:TopMenu />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The TopMenu C# code is here (with the changes I just made):

```
    namespace MyApp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TopMenu : ContentView
    {
        public int userID;
        public void setUserID(int myUserID)
        {
            userID = myUserID;
        }
        public TopMenu () // want to pass in data here
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            //lbl_Top.Text = myUserID.ToString();
        }
```

The ItemScreen C# code is here:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ItemScreen : ContentPage
    {
        public ItemScreen (string itemID)
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            var x = new TopMenu();
            x.setUserID(28);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I pass data into TopMenu from the ItemScreen?

Comment: expose a public property or method that the main page can call when it needs to add data.

Comment: I tried this but the value is not passing over. I think the way I am referencing the other pge in the code is the problem because I am using "new": var x = new TopMenu { }; I figure the "new" is calling the page new again, but not referencing the existing object. Whats the proper way to do this?

Comment: Please show what you’ve actually tried

Comment: I updated my post. Thanks. I'm starting to think I didn't create a property correctly. I thought C# did that for me behind the scenes.

Comment: You don’t need to create a new instance of TopMenu in code, your xaml already does that. You need to give atopMenu a name in the xaml so you can reference it in code

Comment: Where do I do that? I tried to put it in the ContentView using x:Name="", but its not available in the C# code. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign a name in the XAML

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <views:TopMenu x:Name="myMenu" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

then in the code behind

```
    public ItemScreen (string itemID)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        myMenu.setUserID(28);
    }
```

Comment: Once I add the x:Name="myTopMenu" attribute, the compiler throws this error:
 Can't load types from xmlns MyApp.TopMenu.

Maybe I referenced the namespace incorrectly?

Comment: I had to change my XAML to this:
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:BorrowMyBag3.TopMenu"

Comment: Sorry, I need to slow down. Actually, the value is still not actually passing. I am getting no errors, but when I run it and set a breakpoint it says: myTopMenu = Unknown identifier: myTopMenu

Comment: if myTopMenu was unknown it wouldn't even compile.  If you put a breakpoint in setUserID() is it getting called?

Comment: Yes it is getting called actually. Good idea to check that... hmm I'm puzzled

Comment: then what makes you think your value is not being set?

Comment: I am trying to display it on the screen and it doesnt display. Also, when I set a breakpoint, the parameter is: Unknown identifier: myUserID... Maybe the new visual studio is buggy I just updated haha.

Comment: I restarted visual studio and now its working! Thanks a lot!